# How to create a function self to recall element from a matrix in Python

Tags: python, anaconda

I have this script with the class MainColors

```
class MainColors(Flowers, Paints, Authors):
   
     Colors_pencils=(
                      ['RED', 1,3],
                      ['BLUE',1,4],
                      ['BLACK',1,6],
                      ['WHITE',1,10]
                    )
```

How can I create a function that recalls elements of Colors_pencils in other functions of the script? Thank you

Comment: Please explain how is question is related to `spyder`, as you have used this tag

Comment: That sentence does not make much sense to a Python programmer, please be more specific about what you need. i.e. why should `self` be a function and what do you mean by "recall"?

Comment: Do you actually intend for `MainColors` to be a subclass of `Flowers`, `Paints`, and `Authors`? By function do you mean an actual top-level function or a method?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really make it clear what you want to do.

Since `Colors_pencils` is a class variable (and a touple),
you can get elements from it like this `MainColors.Colors_pencils[e]` or `self.Colors_pencils[e]` inside functions of the class.

Comment: thank you for your help, and sorry for my question not so clear but you understood! :)

Comment: @Axe319 right, thanks I corrected it.